# How to prevent a second textchanged event from occurring in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am writing a Visual Basic program in Visual Studio 2012, and I have ran into a problem that I just cannot fix on my own. I am using two text boxes with two combo boxes. There are no buttons in the application. I am using the textchanged event to trigger the calculation as you type in numbers. It will work using one text box, but when it displays the answer in the other text box, it is triggering the text boxes textchanged event. Therefore, not giving me the correct answer.
By the way, this is a unit converter that is converting length such as meter to millimeter, meter to foot, meter to inch, etc...

```
Public Class frmMain
' class-scope variables
Dim decUnit1 As Decimal
Dim decUnit2 As Decimal
Dim intFlag As Integer

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    PopCombo()
    cboUnitType.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub PopCombo()
    ' populates the comboBoxes and sets default selection

    ' populate the comboBox accordingly
    If cboUnitType.SelectedIndex = 0 Then

        ClearBox()

        With Me.cbo1.Items
            .Add("Meter")
            .Add("Milimeter")
            .Add("Foot")
            .Add("Inch")
        End With

        With Me.cbo2.Items
            .Add("Meter")
            .Add("Milimeter")
            .Add("Foot")
            .Add("Inch")
        End With

        ' set default ComboBox index selection
        cbo1.SelectedIndex = 1
        cbo2.SelectedIndex = 3

    ElseIf cboUnitType.SelectedIndex = 1 Then

        ClearBox()

        With Me.cbo1.Items
            .Add("Celsius")
            .Add("Fahrenheit")
        End With

        With Me.cbo2.Items
            .Add("Celsius")
            .Add("Fahrenheit")
        End With

        cbo1.SelectedIndex = 0
        cbo2.SelectedIndex = 1

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ClearBox()
    ' clears the comboBox
    cbo1.Items.Clear()
    cbo2.Items.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub cboUnitType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboUnitType.SelectedIndexChanged
    PopCombo()
End Sub

Private Sub txtUnit1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtUnit1.TextChanged

    Decimal.TryParse(txtUnit1.Text, decUnit1)
    Decimal.TryParse(txtUnit2.Text, decUnit2)

    If cboUnitType.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        ' converts meter to...
        If cbo1.SelectedIndex = 0 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            ' meter
            txtUnit2.Text = txtUnit1.Text
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 0 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            ' millimeter
            txtUnit2.Text = (decUnit1 * 1000).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 0 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            ' foot
            txtUnit2.Text = (decUnit1 * 3.28084).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 0 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
            ' inch
            txtUnit2.Text = (decUnit1 * 39.3701).ToString
        End If

        ' converts millimeter to...
        If cbo1.SelectedIndex = 1 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            ' meter
            txtUnit2.Text = (decUnit1 * 0.001).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 1 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            ' millimeter
            txtUnit2.Text = txtUnit1.Text
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 1 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            ' foot
            txtUnit2.Text = (decUnit1 * 0.00328084).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 1 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
            ' inch
            txtUnit2.Text = (decUnit1 * 0.0393701).ToString
        End If

        ' converts foot to...
        If cbo1.SelectedIndex = 2 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            ' meter
            txtUnit2.Text = (decUnit1 * 0.3048).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 2 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            ' millimeter
            txtUnit2.Text = (decUnit1 * 304.8).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 2 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            ' foot
            txtUnit2.Text = txtUnit1.Text
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 2 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
            ' inch
            txtUnit2.Text = (decUnit1 * 12).ToString
        End If

        ' converts inch to...
        If cbo1.SelectedIndex = 3 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            ' meter
            txtUnit2.Text = (decUnit1 * 0.0254).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 3 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            ' millimeter
            txtUnit2.Text = (decUnit1 * 25.4).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 3 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            ' foot
            txtUnit2.Text = (decUnit1 * 0.0833333).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 3 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
            ' inch
            txtUnit2.Text = txtUnit1.Text
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub txtUnit2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtUnit2.TextChanged

    Decimal.TryParse(txtUnit1.Text, decUnit1)
    Decimal.TryParse(txtUnit2.Text, decUnit2)

    If cboUnitType.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        ' converts meter to...
        If cbo1.SelectedIndex = 0 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            ' meter
            txtUnit1.Text = txtUnit2.Text
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 1 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            ' millimeter
            txtUnit1.Text = (decUnit2 * 1000).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 2 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            ' foot
            txtUnit1.Text = (decUnit2 * 3.28084).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 3 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            ' inch
            txtUnit1.Text = (decUnit2 * 39.3701).ToString
        End If

        ' converts millimeter to...
        If cbo1.SelectedIndex = 0 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            ' meter
            txtUnit1.Text = (decUnit2 * 0.001).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 1 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            ' millimeter
            txtUnit1.Text = txtUnit2.Text
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 2 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            ' foot
            txtUnit1.Text = (decUnit2 * 0.00328084).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 3 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            ' inch
            txtUnit1.Text = (decUnit2 * 0.0393701).ToString
        End If

        ' converts foot to...
        If cbo1.SelectedIndex = 0 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            ' meter
            txtUnit1.Text = (decUnit2 * 0.3048).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 1 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            ' millimeter
            txtUnit1.Text = (decUnit2 * 304.8).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 2 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            ' foot
            txtUnit1.Text = txtUnit2.Text
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 3 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            ' inch
            txtUnit1.Text = (decUnit2 * 12).ToString
        End If

        ' converts inch to...
        If cbo1.SelectedIndex = 0 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
            ' meter
            txtUnit1.Text = (decUnit2 * 0.0254).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 1 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
            ' millimeter
            txtUnit1.Text = (decUnit2 * 25.4).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 2 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
            ' foot
            txtUnit1.Text = (decUnit2 * 0.0833333).ToString
        ElseIf cbo1.SelectedIndex = 3 AndAlso cbo2.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
            ' inch
            txtUnit1.Text = txtUnit1.Text
        End If
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: put the event code into called functions perhaps passing the textbox values as params and return a value (the answer) then when you go to post the answer, set an Ignore flag so that you are not responding to your own changes.  WHen the flag is true, dont call the new  procs. (Basically need to isolate the calcs from the events so you can break the cycle). Might be easier to just add a Calc button.

Comment: Could you give me some example code of this Ignore Flag? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have recursive events here, the txtUnit1 event handler modifies txtUnit2.  Which will trigger the event for txtUnit2 which modifies txtUnit1 again.  This is normally a fatal mishap that crashes your program but it should in fact work here.  Since the conversion back should produce the exact same text as is already in the textbox so the event should not fire.  Use a debugger to find out why the text doesn't match.  Pretty good debugging learning exercise btw, the point of this assignment presumably :)

Comment: It seems like you can type into TB1 to get an answer in TB2 or vice versa.  Change the paradigm to `From Tb1 = > To Tb2` so that no one types into TB2 (rather than `TB1 <=> TB2`). ELiminates the whole problem.  Use the combos to change the conversion units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a boolean variable or two to suppress the text changed events when update the Text property of the text boxes.  Here's an example that converts degrees F to C and back, and lets you type in a value in either text box:

```
Public Class Form4

    Dim suppressTextBox1TextChanged As Boolean = False
    Dim suppressTextBox2TextChanged As Boolean = False

    Private Sub txtDegreesF_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtDegreesF.TextChanged
        'Convert to Celsius

        'Only do the calculation if we are typing the textbox
        If Not suppressTextBox1TextChanged Then
            Dim degreesF As Double
            Dim degreesC As Double
            If Double.TryParse(txtDegreesF.Text, degreesF) Then
                degreesC = (degreesF - 32) * (5 / 9)
                suppressTextBox2TextChanged = True
                txtDegreesC.Text = degreesC.ToString()
                suppressTextBox2TextChanged = False
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtDegreesC_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtDegreesC.TextChanged
        'Convert to Fahrenheit

        'Only do the calculation if we are typing the textbox
        If Not suppressTextBox2TextChanged Then
            Dim degreesF As Double
            Dim degreesC As Double
            If Double.TryParse(txtDegreesC.Text, degreesC) Then
                degreesF = (degreesC * 1.8) + 32
                suppressTextBox1TextChanged = True
                txtDegreesF.Text = degreesF.ToString()
                suppressTextBox1TextChanged = False
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```